# src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ST' to a(n) 'type definition' component in HL7

Tags: java, xsd, xsd-validation, hl7

I am working with **HL7 version 2.7.1**.
I have downloaded the respective XSDs (total 197 numbers of XSD) from hl7 site.
Link: http://www.hl7.org/documentcenter/private/standards/V271/HL7-xml%20v2.7.1.zip
I have written some java code trying to assign schema to Schema object and schema gives me error.
The error is: **src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ST' to a(n) 'type definition' component.**

```
        /**
 * Validating XML with XSD
 * @param inputXml
 * @param schemaLocation
 * @return returns validation true/false 
 * @throws SAXException
 */
public boolean isValidXML(String inputXml, String schemaLocation)
        throws SAXException {
    // build the schema
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory
            .newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    File schemaFile = new File(schemaLocation);
    Schema schema = null;
    Validator validator = null;
    try {
        //TODO: Failed in this line. schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
        schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
        validator = schema.newValidator();
```

After that I am checking the schema at oXygen XML Editor and get the same error. 
"src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ST' to a(n) 'type definition' component."
PFA: screenshoot[image]
I am looking for the XSD file which reference to the XSD file contains the 'ST' definition.
If I am wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Data type **ST** is "string". You can find its definition (for your use) in all HL7 specifications, e.g. in chapter "2.8 DATA TYPES" in [Health Level Seven, Version 2.3.1 © 1999 (online PDF)](http://pacs.hk/Doc/HL7/Hl7V231.pdf)

In the XSD documents all data type definitions should be in file `datatypes.xsd`

I remember that there were some errors in the schema as it was and that I also tried to use [Version 2 v2.xml XML Schemas for HL7 Version 2.5 and earlier (Sun_HL7v2xsd.zip)](http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=214) where were less errors but only definitions up to version 2.5.1

I'm not sure what exactly is your use case what exactly you need to be able to do, what systems you need to interface with and what code base you already have etc. as it is not visible even from your other HL7 questions - but..

..in our system we have finally settled on

- not using strongly type grammar enforced by schemas as several systems we are interfacing don't quite follow them
- most messages that flow through our systems are in HL7 v2.3, v2.3.1 and very few in HL7 v2.5 (all of them **MUST** be supported at the same time)
- we use simple generic parser that can parse nearly anything that looks like binary HL7 message. Interpretation of segments and fields is up to another software layer where the set of restrictions determininig which messages are good and which messages are bad - is configurable

If I'd implement support for another protocol or another protocol version I would follow similar approach. Loading bunch of XSDs and generating another bunch of classes that can represent them in memory just to enable IntelliSense in code editor - would not be my preferfed implementation decision

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying to converting HL7 v2.7.1 message to XML using java code, I am able to convert them to XML, After conversion, for validation purpose need the corresponding XSDs to validate the XMLs. For the other versions (before 2.6 using the same approach as mentioned by you) but that parser don't have support for 2.7.1 version

Comment: @user1321939 I'm sorry, I don't have any better answer for you. I would have to search for better answer using Google (e.g. [this](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=9094) :) Do you really have to support HL7 v2.7.1 and process them in the XML format? Can't you just skip straight over to HL7 v3? It should be much easier to process, validate etc. ([Key Differences Between HL7 V2 and V3](http://www.hl7standards.com/blog/2007/12/12/key-differences-between-hl7-v2-and-v3/))